# iOS Fixed position date and time?

Tags: ios, time

I am looking for a clock which extends through the life of the iOS Device, and is always unique, and is not adjustable by the user.

The primary reason for this is for a game where real world time is taken into account, so we don't want the user to have the ability to adjust that time.   Also the game does not require that the device be online, so that's not something I can rely on.